# Running SonarQube without TFS Build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, sonarqube

I was asked to integrate another project (C#) into SonarQube. We use TFS 2013, SonarQube 5.1.2 with Sonar.MSBuild.Runner 1.0.
The Build process template is old (does not support pre and post Powershell scripts) and it is customized. Visual Studio 2013 is unable to edit the old build process template.

I tried to do just the static code analysis and run the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner with the start parameter and a second time with the end parameter without doing a build in between (The code coverage does not seem important to them). But then I get the error `"No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Check that the analysis targets are referenced by the MSBuild projects being build"?`

What options do I have to integrate this project into SonarQube?

Comment: What version of TFS do you have on build controller/agent?

Comment: It is also TFS 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the MSBuild SonarQube Runner from the command line, you have to:

1. Prepare the environment: `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:SQ_project_key /n:SQ_project_name /v:SQ_project_version` (pick arbitrary SonarQube project key, name and version)
2. Run your build: `msbuild`
3. Upload analysis results: `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end`

The MSBuild SonarQube Runner integrates with MSBuild and collects informations as it builds your project: You must run the build during the `begin` and `end` invocations, or this mandatory information won't be available and the MSBuild SonarQube Runner will fail with the message you reported. The MSBuild integration is compatible with MSBuild versions 4.0, 12 and 14.

Regarding the integration with TFS XAML builds, if you're using a customized one, you'll have to customize it a bit more to integrate the calls to the `begin`and `end` commands of the MSBuild SonarQube Runner.

Code Coverage is supported out of the box on TFS 2013 with the default build definition template, you just need to run tests with coverage enabled. If that doesn't work for you, see this link on how to manually pass the code coverage results path property: http://docs.sonarqube.org/x/CoBh

Comment: How does msbuild know to run SonarQube.Integration.targets?

Comment: During `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runer.exe begin`, a bootstrapper `.targets` file is deployed to a special MSBuild `ImportsBefore` folder, see https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-msbuild-runner/blob/1.1/SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor/TargetsInstaller.cs - That bootstrapping `.targets` file will include `SonarQube.Integration.targets` if it exists in the current's directory `.sonarqube` subfolder. See https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-msbuild-runner/blob/1.1/SonarQube.MSBuild.Tasks/Targets/SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets

Comment: Please post a separate question if for some reason you have to customize any of this logic: We do not expect this to happen, and make changes to these targets file in almost every release. Changing them will make it harder for you to update versions in the future, so perhaps your use case can be covered out of the box if that's not yet the case.

Comment: I'm not customizing that logic. I was building a solution using `Microsoft.Build` api and realized that `ImportsBefore` is not being picked up. After lot of searching and reading, I came to understand that `ImportsBefore`/`ImportsAfter` is MSBuild specific logic and that API has no comparable.

Comment: How can I integrate tfs build with sonar running locally on `http://localhost:9000` ?